# Unix way to extract vectorised image and its graph from a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, images

Data: [one LHC thesis' page 16](https://inspirehep.net/record/1339953/files/TS2014_013_2.pdf#page=16), where the picture is vectorised (most probably .eps). 
I am reviewing the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14440/3017) of the thread *Software needed to scrape data from graph*.
I cannot find any tool that is made to extract .eps image from a PDF file. 
My whole system's pseudocode

1. Neutralise PDF file by `gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=newfile.pdf badfile.pdf` ([source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/difficulties-with-importing-pdfs-in-mathematica/2783#2783))
2. Find native resolution for the extraction of the vectorised image from a pdf file. (**not sure about this one because no zooming may be necessary;** 100% zoom level of Adobe view cannot be optimal with a screenshot)
3. extract vectorised image from a pdf file (**current goal**)
4. extract graph from .eps image

where doing all in the same system would be great.

### Open tools with (3)

Possible image formats png/xpm/jpeg/tiff/pnm/ras/bmp/gif

- `g3data` but no .eps format
- Engaude-digitizer is active [here](https://github.com/markummitchell/engauge-digitizer), and more popular than `R digitize`.
- `R digitize` was removed from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/digitize/index.html), because no maintainer power; but now in tpoisot's Github [here](https://github.com/tpoisot/digitize) and its review in Luke's blog [Digitizing data from old plots using ‘digitize’](http://lukemiller.org/index.php/2011/06/digitizing-data-from-old-plots-using-digitize/) but they are trying to get back to CRAN [here](https://github.com/tpoisot/digitize/pull/8) a ticket. I have experienced a sequence of problems with the software [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281674/16920). One big weakness is that they sensor their github, and no feedback is welcome.

### Systems with (3) and (4)

- most probably R package which can do both things:

### Tools only with (3) or (4) or none

- Task (4) can be done in Mathematica as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85329/9815) about *Is it possible to extract data from an eps plot not generated in Mathematica*. However, Mathematica not suitable for Task (3) according to devtalk.
- Adobe Acrobat > Editing. I could not find any suitable method to do it. It seems that no Linux version in Ubuntu 16.04.

### From vectorized and Steps (1-2)

Drag-and-drop of the figure does not work here. 
So must programmatically extract the figure from the pdf. 
There exists a terminal tool for that which extract all images/eps/... from the document, but I have no idea how well they do what they do. 
I would like to find here something which is just good in extracting the .eps image from a pdf file.

### From Rasterized to Vectorized and Steps (1-2)

Example image for DavidLeBauer about the insersection of the graph with the x-axis for the discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14440/3017)

[image]

and second example about points intersecting two axes here for David

[image]

Code

```
% https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281211/16920
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=data_clean.pdf badfile.pdf

% drag and drop picture from data_clean.pdf to your folder in Ubuntu 16.04 by having the default zoom level; I think zoom should not affect here the result of drag-and-drop
% Result: image.png

% g3data image.png
% bug in 16.04: http://askubuntu.com/q/767982/25388

% open figure in ubuntu - Print to File > Ps.
% Result: image.png.ps

ps2eps image.png.ps
% Result: image.png.eps

% https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85320/9815
%% Mathematica starts here 

(* Wolfram Language Test file *)

fig = Import["image.png.eps"]

Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/shortInputForm/master/shortInputForm.m"]

fig // shortInputForm

% Run but get error: http://askubuntu.com/q/767992/25388
% NB this error comes too if I have no code in the editor. So something wrong in my way of doing this. I am amateur in Mathematica.
```

---

How can you extract .eps image and its graph from a pdf file in Unix way?

Comment: this might help, although I'm not sure how well it'll work on a vector image: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150100/extracting-embedded-images-from-a-pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sufficient supported solution exists for the case because the problem is hard inverse-problem in reality. 
Mathematica solutions have also significant problems with real-world applications.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really answer the original question.

**Inkscape** makes it possible to import a page from a .pdf while preserving vectorial information. It is then possible to save in .svg format.

**Reading the .svg** file is then possible if you want to extract the paths/points coordinates. Some tweaking (basically scaling and offsetting) is however necessary if you want to go back to graph coordinates.

I tried to write a python code for reading the .svg file and get back the points in graph coordinates, based on [svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) format definition. It is however under development and requires to clean the graph before by keeping only the curves and the bare axes.