# How to Install R's devtools and digitize?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, r

I need *devtools* because I need the function *install_github* to install the non-CRAN package *digitize* [here](https://github.com/tpoisot/digitize).
I installed `R` by

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-robustbase
```

I did not install R's packages right away, as terdon's answer proposes, but I could correct the permissions:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/lib/R/site-library/
```

which I think is the default setting. 
I then had to do as rcs' answer proposes, to successfully install `devtools` and `tpoisot/digitize` but only with

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
R
install.packages('httr')
install.packages('git2r')
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
install.packages('readbitmap')
install_github('tpoisot/digitize')
```

The output of the last command can be

```
Skipping install for github remote, the SHA1 (d16e28b9) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
```

Do `install_github('tpoisot/digitize', force = TRUE)` but you may get

```
...
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpX8eOLX/devtools57475d25a113/tpoisot-digitize-d16e28b'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I could not find a way to install digitize without `sudo`. So do `sudo R`, and repeat the same and you get

```
...
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmpAlAT4e/devtools57e864e8c490/tpoisot-digitize-d16e28b'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘digitize’ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (digitize)
```

Add `masi` to the existing group `staff` to work without `sudo` in `R`; which you need also in a fresh installation

```
sudo usermod -a -G staff masi
```

### Tests of the installation

1. I follow the guide [here](http://lukemiller.org/index.php/2011/06/digitizing-data-from-old-plots-using-digitize/). I start `R` in `$HOME/Pictures/` without `sudo` and use their test image [here](http://lukemiller.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Rintro-snail1.jpg).
2. Select four points in the axes with mouse `cal = digitize::ReadAndCal('Rintro-snail1.jpg')`

[image]

3. Do `data.points = digitize::DigitData(col = 'red')` and choose manually points which are your data points

[image]

4. I close the Plot window by doing second-click.
5. Do `df = digitize::Calibrate(data.points, cal, 0.1, 0.4, 0.0, 0.6)` and seeing `df`

   ```
          x  y
   1  71.50 NA
   2  65.65 NA
   ...
   24 26.80 NA
   ```

   Doing `head(df)`

   ```
         x  y
   1 71.50 NA
   2 65.65 NA
   3 64.60 NA
   4 60.85 NA
   5 59.05 NA
   6 58.15 NA
   ```

### Installation Details

- In `R` and without `sudo`

  ```
  > .Library
  [1] "/usr/lib/R/library"
  > > .libPaths()
  [1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
  [3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
  ```
- Command `ls /usr/lib/R/library/` which does not list `devtools`. Why?

  ```
  base       compiler   grid        methods   rpart    survival
  boot       datasets   KernSmooth  mgcv      spatial  tcltk
  class      foreign    lattice     nlme      splines  tools
  cluster    graphics   MASS        nnet      stats    translations
  codetools  grDevices  Matrix      parallel  stats4   utils
  ```
- Command `ls -la /usr/local/lib/R/`

  ```
  total 12
  drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff 4096 touko 19 22:25 .
  drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 touko 19 22:25 ..
  drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 touko 19 22:25 site-library
  ```
- Command `ls -la /usr/local/lib/`

  ```
  total 20
  drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 touko 19 22:25 .
  drwxr-xr-x 14 root root  4096 touko 19 22:13 ..
  drwxrwsr-x  4 root staff 4096 huhti 21 01:13 python2.7
  drwxrwsr-x  3 root staff 4096 huhti 21 01:08 python3.5
  drwxrwsr-x  3 root staff 4096 touko 19 22:25 R
  ```
- Command `R_LIBS_USER="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/" R`

  ```
   R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
   Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
   ...
  ```
- `library(devtools)` gets loaded

### Differential tools

- This project is more popular and can work better  https://github.com/markummitchell/engauge-digitizer

Reasons for previous bugs

- No clean system: systems which were upgraded from 14.04, 15.10, etc.
- Messed up permissions/owners because of the previous thing.
- Own mistakes in the process.
- No backups in the case of failure.
- ...
- missing docs

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit in a clean installation
Hardware: Dell PC 2013, Macbook Air 2013-mid, ...

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my Arch system. Installing `devtools` through `sudo R`, let me run `library(devtools)` from a non-sudo R session. Please add the output of i) `.Library` run from a normal `R` session and ii) from `sudo R` and iii) check for a `devtools` subdirectory in the path provided by those commands. On my system, it's at `/usr/lib64/R/library/devtools/`.

Comment: OK, is there a `devtools` subdirectory in `/usr/lib/R/library`?

Comment: My guess is that the installation wasn't actually successful then. Try it again,  and pay close attention to the output. Were you *really* able to run `library(devtools)` and successfully load the library?

Comment: OK, I think I know what the problem is. One more thing, what do you get if you run `.libPaths()` from R?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Argh, OK, and do you have a devtools subdir in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`? You probably do. If so, see my (newly) updated answer.

Comment: That's OK, that's because you don't have permissions to read that. Try `sudo ls /usr/local/lib/R/site-library`. Even better, ping me in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) and we can sort this out. You seem to have screwed up the permissions in `/usr/local/lib/R`.

Comment: That's a completely different issue and not really on topic here. You have successfully installed everything, now you need help running an R script. I recommend you ask on [so] instead.

Comment: The only issue I see here is that closing the graph window unsets the variable. Is there anything else left?

Comment: This question combines a linux installation issue with the issue of using the digitize package. The latter problem isn't linux/unix issue but is answered here https://github.com/tpoisot/digitize/issues/11

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`httr` imports the `openssl` package which needs as system requirement `libssl-dev` (`sudo apt install libssl-dev`)

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
...
```

The `curl` package needs as system requirement `libcurl4-openssl-dev`:

```
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
...
```

So, to install you will need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then start an R shell with `sudo R` and:

```
install.packages('httr')
install.packages('git2r')
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
install_github('tpoisot/digitize')
```

Comment: I accept this answer because it was a good starter. After `devtools`, you need `install.packages('readbitmap')`, please see the body for the final version.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you don't just change the permissions of system directories! That's what root access is for. Put the permissions back the way you found them and next time run `sudo R` and `install.packages` from the resulting, root R shell.

Now, the reason you can't install is right there in the output you show:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
```

Apparently, [as explained by rcs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html), on Ubuntu, you need to install `libssl-dev` and `libcurl4-openssl-dev` first.

---

The next issue is that your root user's R installation has `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` as the first directory in the output of `.libPaths` and that is not in the paths of your regular user. Since it is the first entry for root, that's where your library was installed:

```
 Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

So, a simple solution is to create a file called `~/.Rprofile` and add this line to it:

```
.libPaths("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/")
```

Alternatively, or additionally, you could include a line like

```
   .libPaths("/home/masi/Rlibs")
```

That would let you install libraries into the directory `/home/masi/Rlibs`  (chose whatever name you want) in future and so avoid the need for `sudo R`.

---

Alternatively, you could set the environmental variable `R_LIBS_USER` to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/` (or `/home/masi/Rlibs` or wherever else your libraries are being installed). Just add this line to your `~/.profile`:

```
R_LIBS_USER=/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/
```

Comment: @Masi did you try my suggestions above? You can test that this is the problem by running `R_LIBS_USER="/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/" R` and then, in R, run `library(devtools)`.

Comment: If you execute `.libPaths("/home/masi/Rlibs")` after `.libPaths("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/")` that will replace the original setting. If you want to add a library directory it should be `.libPaths(c(.libPaths(), "/home/masi/Rlibs") )`