# Why this error about upstart/systemd with runit?

Tags: software-installation, upstart, runit

I run `sudo apt-get install git-all` in Ubuntu 16.04 and see the following in the end

```
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
dpkg: error processing package runit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of git-daemon-run:
 git-daemon-run depends on runit; however:
  Package runit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 runit
 git-daemon-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I get the error after rebooting my system also. It really blocks my whole system. 
I run `killall update-notifier`. I run `sudo apt-get install git-all` but 
I get the same error message. I run `pgrep -a apt` but get nothing as output. I run `pgrep -a update` but get nothing as output. 
A bug report about the case [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1584214).

- In Grub, Choose *Advanced options* > *Ubuntu (Upstart) Linux kernel 4.22*. Doing the same only in terminal without *systemd* causes the same error.

---

Why is this error here with runit?

Comment: @terdon Can you review the problem here? It came in the fresh Ubuntu and is blocking the processing of the thread http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281674/16920 too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gerrit Pape](http://smarden.org/pape/), who maintains both xyr own runit and Bernstein's daemontools packages for Debian, is one of the few developers that took the idea of "init-system neutrality" (that was much bandied about after the Debian systemd hoo-hah) really to heart and has tried hard to support running these under van Smoorenburg `init`, upstart, and systemd.

The post-installation maintainer script for runit you will find unpacked on your system from the package somewhere such as `/var/lib/dpkg/info/runit.postinst`.  As you can see, it tries to detect the presence of upstart and start the `runsvdir` upstart job if upstart is present.  It does the same with systemd and `runit.service`.

Unfortunately, on Ubuntu 14 and later *both* systemd *and* upstart are installed.  And so the post-installation maintainer script for the package is trying to run the upstart job with upstart's `start` command.  Of course, upstart isn't (by default) the system-wide service manager in Ubuntu 15 and later, and upstart's `start` command fails to work.

The following is a rough idea of how to patch the script in order to overcome this:

```
…
if test -r /usr/share/debconf/confmodule; then
  . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
  db_purge
fi

if test -d /run/systemd/system ; then
  systemctl start runit.service
elif test -x /sbin/start ; then
  /sbin/start runsvdir
fi
```

This is not ideal, but it is a beginning.  `runit.prerm` and `runit.postrm` likewise require some adjustments.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014-11-04). [*runit*](https://lists.debian.org/debian-vote/2014/11/msg00059.html).  debian-vote mailing list.
- Nikolay Hristov (2014-10-21). [*runit: Fails to install runit after fresh install of jessie beta2*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766187).  Debian Bug #766187.
- Andreas Beckmann (2014-11-03). [*daemontools-run: fails to install without /etc/inittab*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=767933).  Debian Bug #767933.
- [`runit.postinst`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/runit/wily/view/head:/debian/runit.postinst#L49).  *runit source*.  Ubuntu Launchpad.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196252/5132

Comment: I updated the body. I really cannot find a workaround. I have not yet tested your solution because I cannot understand the complete resolution. Can you propose more? This is a fresh Ubuntu installation so it is strange that such a bug is there. Is there any complete workaround for this? Why does the problem occurs? For me, it seems to be a bug in the system, but I would not like to accept it.

Comment: I opened a bug report about the case here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1584214

Comment: I choose *Ubuntu (upstart)* in Grub, and I run the *apt-get* command. I get the same error. Is this startup without *systemd* really?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a temporary solution to the problem. Change the location of source servers, etc from the main server to Finland or to Estonia. It resolves the acute problem for a while.