# How to Find LaTeX generated PDF files?

Tags: ubuntu, find, osx, latex

I need to find LaTeX Generated PDF files because I want to find those files made by me. I think `find` could possibly work here.

### OS X El-Capitan

I run Ulrich's proposal `find BitTorrentSync/ -exec pdfinfo {} + |grep pdftex` but I get

```
find: pdfinfo: No such file or directory
find: pdfinfo: No such file or directory
...
```

where the problem is that I do not have `pdfinfo` yet in my system.

L.Levrel's proposal. I run `gfind -name '*.pdf' | gxargs ggrep -al '^/Producer (pdfTeX'` where I use GNU's products but I get in OS X El-Capitan

```
gxargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
ggrep: cademic: invalid context length argument
```

### Ubuntu 16.04

I cannot run Ulrich's proposal because of the bug [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284249/16920).
L.Levrel's first proposal does not work but it works with `xargs -0`

```
find -name '*.pdf' | xargs -0 grep -al '^/Producer (pdfTeX'
```

---

How can you `find` LaTeX generated PDF files?

Comment: The output of `pdfinfo` will include the creator (software), depending on your workflow that would include strings like "pdftex" or "dvipdf" or "dvips". So, vaguely, first `find` all pdfs, `-exec` `pdfinfo` on each and inspect its output with `grep`?

Comment: Install pdfinfo

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @fd0 I am using OS X El-Capitan and Ubuntu 16.04. See the body for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on L.Levrel response, using the tools supplied in OS X (this should also work in Ubuntu).

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec grep -alE '/Producer \(pdfTeX|/Producer\(pdfTeX' {} +
```

Comment: Your command works both in OS X El-Capitan and Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the "/Producer" line:

```
find -name '*.pdf' | xargs grep -al '^/Producer (pdfTeX'
```

or with double quotes

```
find -name '*.pdf' | xargs grep -al "^/Producer (pdfTeX"
```

or with null-separated list of files

```
find -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -al '^/Producer (pdfTeX'
```

Comment: Unexpected token ')'? There's no ')' in the command.

Comment: My output is the expected list of files. The fact you have to call `gfoo` for the GNU `foo` makes me think you're not on Linux. What OS then? Specify it in your question and/or tags.

Comment: I am using OS X El-Capitan and Ubuntu 16.04. I cannot understand why GNU products do not work in OS X.