# Extract Part of a Single PDF Page from Bash

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

In order to extract a part of a PDF page on a Gnu/Linux machine I use the following command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf -g2300x2300 input.pdf
```

The `-g...x...` option lets me choose coordinates on the input PDF. So, here is my question:

1. How do I shift the coordinates so that any rectangle on the input PDF might be chosen?

and extending that question:

2. Is there any graphical interface that allows choosing the coordinates I want? (so far it's trial and error.)

---

I do not want to extract whole pages from the input PDF.

The output format should again be PDF. I am not looking for extraction of text or images.

A similar question had been asked on [askubuntu.org](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf), but the answers only deal with extracting whole pages or page ranges. I know I can do that with `pdftk`.

A yet more specific question similar to this on was asked [here before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281211/unix-way-to-extract-vectorised-image-and-its-graph-from-a-pdf-file), but remained unanswered.

On a Mac this whole affair is absolutely simple: The program `preview` has a function for exactly that. How do I snapshot a part of a single PDF page to output format PDF?

Comment: You can do this in a UI by importing the PDF into Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

You could give `pdfjam` a try, which accepts parameters like `--trim '1cm 2cm 1cm 2cm' --clip true` (and more parameters the LaTeX package 'pdfpages' has) "to trim those amounts from left, bottom, right and top, respectively, of input pages", like the '--help' output for the program states.

Comment: and then trial and error until I get the margins right?

Comment: unfortunately, yes. By the way: here is a ghostscript answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/592206

Comment: @jaleks, I tried the solution you linked to but it didn't crop the image when I tried it on a pdf containing svg graphics. One useful thing thing I did find out reading `info gv` is that there is a config file which, if you set the `GV.saveposFilename` variable , appends the current mouse ordinates to a file on each `z` keypress.

Answer (score -1):

I use document snippets a lot but I haven't seen a GUI way to extract pdf snippets directly.

That said, a precise snippet selection can be made through `Okular` or with `Spectacle` and the result saved as png, which I **know** you said you didn't want, but ..... you can get back to pdfs if you run this on the directory you saved the snippets to

```
for i in *.png; do convert $i ${i%.*}.pdf; done
```

The question you referenced is not so much to do with just 'grabbing a piece of a document' but reverse engineering curves without having the base point/plot data. Different animal to the question you phrased.

Comment: `Okular` seems a good choice to display the size of the  rectangle. However, converting to `png` pixelizes the image. I do want the vector graphics.

Comment: That's true, though I usually dodge the resolution issue by enlarging the image on the screen and since most of my work is processed scans I am never going to get VG quality out. So you are saying 'Preview' effectively take a viewport from a VG rendering? Interesting.

Comment: The long way round you can crop in [inkscape](https://inkscapetutorials.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/inkscape-faq-how-do-i-crop-in-inkscape/) and print the cropped image to pdf. Once you open the new pdf you can manipulate the viewported svg or copy it into another pdf.